# Specular reflection is not correct

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, light

I'm trying to make a little 3D engine for my master degree (and for my skill). I have a problem on the specular reflection. (I'm sorry for the link for the illustration image but I haven't enough reputation yet). All sources is available on my GitHub : [DWRenderer](https://github.com/Zethzer/DWRenderer)

[image: Image of the problem]

Right here, we're behing the object but the camera is on the front also the light. As we can see, there's a reflection behind the object.

For describe the actual parameters, all the computations are made in world space (normally... with that problem, I've a doubt). I put the camera on position vec3(0, 0, 3) for the test and the light is just a point at vec3(1.2, 1, 2) represent by a cube. I'm using Qt 5.4 and OpenGL 4.1 under Ubuntu with Nvidia drivers.

Here's my vertex shader :

```
#version 410 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;

out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0f));
    Normal = normalMatrix * normal;
}
```

And my fragment shader:

```
#version 410 core

out vec4 color;

in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;

struct Material {
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct Light {
    vec3 position;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

uniform Material material;
uniform Light light;

uniform vec3 viewPos;

void main()
{
    // Vectors
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - FragPos);
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);

    // Ambient
    vec3 ambient = material.ambient * light.ambient;

    // Diffuse
    float diff = clamp(dot(lightDir, norm), 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * material.diffuse * light.diffuse;

    // Specular - The bug seems only here
    float spec = pow(clamp(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0, 1.0), material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = spec * material.specular * light.specular;

    vec3 result = (diffuse + specular + ambient);
    color = vec4(result, 1.0f);

    // For test vectors
    //color = vec4(specular, 1.0f);
}
```

And the code in the gaming loop (paintGL with a time with an interval of 16ms for real-time) for initialize the uniform variable (The position of the camera for the shader is fixed, i can turn around my cube for check the bug. The position of the light is in "initializeGL" and fixed too) :

```
// Draw cube
    m_cubeShader->useShaderProgram();
    GLint lightPosLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "light.position");
    GLint viewPosLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "viewPos");
    GLint matAmbientLoc  = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "material.ambient");
    GLint matDiffuseLoc  = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "material.diffuse");
    GLint matSpecularLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "material.specular");
    GLint matShineLoc    = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "material.shininess");
    GLint lightAmbientLoc  = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "light.ambient");
    GLint lightDiffuseLoc  = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "light.diffuse");
    GLint lightSpecularLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "light.specular");
    glUniform3f(lightAmbientLoc,  0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
    glUniform3f(lightDiffuseLoc,  0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glUniform3f(lightSpecularLoc, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glUniform3f(matAmbientLoc,  1.0f, 0.5f, 0.31f);
    glUniform3f(matDiffuseLoc,  1.0f, 0.5f, 0.31f);
    glUniform3f(matSpecularLoc, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glUniform1f(matShineLoc,    32.0f);
    glUniform3f(viewPosLoc, 0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f); // For testing a bug - Unresolved
    //glUniform3f(viewPosLoc, m_camera->getPosition().x, m_camera->getPosition().y, m_camera->getPosition().z);
    glUniform3f(lightPosLoc, m_lightPos.x, m_lightPos.y, m_lightPos.z);

    glm::mat4 model;
    glm::mat4 view;
    glm::mat4 projection;
    glm::mat3 normalMatrix;
    normalMatrix = glm::mat3(glm::transpose(glm::inverse(model)));
    view = m_camera->getViewMatrix();
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(m_camera->getFov()), (GLfloat)m_screenWidth / (GLfloat)m_screenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    GLint normalMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "normalMatrix");
    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "model");
    GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "view");
    GLint projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_cubeShader->getId(), "projection");
    glUniformMatrix3fv(normalMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(normalMatrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    glBindVertexArray(m_cubeVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Draw light
    m_lightShader->useShaderProgram();

    model = glm::mat4();
    model = glm::translate(model, m_lightPos);
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f));
    modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_lightShader->getId(), "model");
    viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_lightShader->getId(), "view");
    projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_lightShader->getId(), "projection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    glBindVertexArray(m_lightVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I've tried to do the computations on view space but it doesn't work. I've tried to modify/normalize/use max() instead of clamp() but after a few hours on the problem. I'm out of any ideas.

Comment: where is your object defined, where is it centered ?

Comment: He's define in initializeGL function (vertices and normal) and using a VAO and VBO. He's centered on origin (0,0,0).On the sources on github, it's the file renderer.cpp

Comment: i don't get the phrase `there's a reflection behind the object`, what do you call behind ? since the light and viewer are the same side of the object (both positive positions compared to null position for cube on z axis), how can you see `behind` ?

Comment: I can see "behind" by moving the camera. But for the shader, i compute the calculations with a fixed camera at (0,0,3). Like that, i can verify the rendering behind the object.

Comment: so the picture you linked doesn't show the actual problem ?

Comment: Yes. It does of course. On the picture you have a view of the back of the cube. But the camera is on the front and the light too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time !
Apparently, it's seems because of a stupid thing. Reflection is compute by view position and light position (etc) but in OpenGL, that seems there are not collision. So reflection compute the front face and the inside front face (back face) and if we move for see the back, we see that computation. (from the inside). If I move the camera normally, all computation seems correct.

Comment: exactly what i was trying to explain in my answer and i drawn a nice scheme :-( , but the fact that you know why it bugs with fixed testing values maybe doesn't explain everything ,btw the scheme for anybody who would have not understood :-P http://i.stack.imgur.com/yDZgK.png

Comment: Sorry for the wasting time for the scheme :( But, like I said, thanks for your time :) And I never use fixed value anymore for positions :p only the colors :p

Comment: but i thought you were using fixed position **because** you had bugs first to try to debug it, whatever, everything works fine ? marvellous

Comment: No exactly. I fixed the camera just for fun & see what we obtain. And what I thought he was a bug, he wasn't ^^'

Answer (score 1):

You only have diffuse and specular light if the `lightDir` (direction from fragment to light) is in the direction of `norm` ( normal vector of fragment ). If they are directed against you can do without diffuse and specular light. In other words, if ther isn't any diffuse light (because `diff` is `0.0`), there isn't any specular light too. Adapt your code like this:

```
void main()
{
    // Vectors
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - FragPos);
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);

    // Ambient
    vec3 ambient = material.ambient * light.ambient;

    vec3 result = ambient;
    float dotNvLd = dot( norm, lightDir );
    if ( dotNvLd > 0.0 ) // test if normal vector not directed against vector to light position
    {
        // Diffuse
        float diff = min( dotNvLd, 1.0 );
        vec3 diffuse = diff * material.diffuse * light.diffuse;

        // Specular - The bug seems only here
        float spec = pow(clamp(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0, 1.0),   material.shininess);
        vec3 specular = spec * material.specular * light.specular;

        result = (diffuse + specular + ambient);
    }

    color = vec4(result, 1.0f);

    // For test vectors
    //color = vec4(specular, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't understand why

Comment: @Zethzer If `lightDir` is directed ageinst `norm`, the fragment is lighted on backface, so you can`t see the light on frontface.